# Are Sparklines Viewable via excel services and Business Intelligence?

Tags: 2010, excel-services

I have an excel report with SparkLines in it.  When I view the file through excel services (aka in the browser), all looks fine and dandy.  But when I try to browse the file via REST services, the charts\ranges dont show SparkLines.

Are SparkLines supported via REST services?  Is there any way I can show SparkLine charting data in a Business Intelligence site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the excel chart web part. Here is an article explaining various methods of obtaining chart data and displaying chart data in a BI site. I believe you can access the data if you use the excel chart web part since it stores the data as a list. Take a look below

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=816

Comment: Thanks for the help Joseph, unfortunately this isn't exactly what I was hoping for.  If I view the whole worksheet through SharePoint, the sparkline charts show in the appropriate cell.  But when I browse the file via ranges, none of the sparklines appear.  I was hoping to just use the exising spartlines because of the formatting our analysis team had already customized on the excel report..

Comment: There is a way to do it as you said. Try this article it is for SharePoint 2007 but you should be able to adapt to 2010. I know what you are trying to do is possible try this link. it will use excel services to pull the chart only. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22239/Displaying-Charts-in-SharePoint-using-Excel-Servic

Comment: Thanks Joseph, that's close to what we need to do, but it doesn't work the same way.  Sparklines aren't like other charts, you can't "name" them like you can other charts.  As such, you can't make them a publishable item..

Comment: I really can't think of another way other than making the data available and re developing an ASP.NET sparkline solution. I hope you can get what you need. I am still trying to find a solution I will post when I can find one.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I really do appreciate the help!  I did find something close here: http://sharepintblog.com/2011/10/02/create-sharepoint-list-view-sparklines-from-version-history/ - but thats ridding of sparklines and using Googles charting API's.  Not that this wouldnt work, but trying to refrain from breaking "too much" of existing functionality.. unless I have to, of course.

Comment: Well you can do it in the sharepoint environment. You need to get the data from excel into a list and have it automatically update. then add a SharePoint Chart Web Part and point it to the list. If you do that then you can have your sparkline chart.

Comment: Yep thanks Joseph, in the end it looks like Im going down this road after all, finally found that sparklines just arent "published" per this blog as well.  Thanks for the help!  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2009/11/17/excel-services-rest-limitations.aspx

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hope you can work it out.